# sharepoint 2010 Oracle Integration issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We are in the process of integrating sharepoint 2010 with oracle HRMS system.

Our development environment is :

windows server 2008 x64

sharepoint 2010 x64

visual studio 2010 x32

sql server 2008 x64

Now,  when i used Oracle client 11g R2 64 bit (64 bit oracle.dataaccess.dll) for connectivity to oracle, visual studio being 32bit not able to load 64bit oracle.dataaccess.dll and is reporting build errors of project.

when i tried Oralce client 11g R2 32 bit (32bit oracle.dataaccess.dll) for connectivity to oracle, visual studio is able to load 32bit oracle.dataaccess.dll but w3wp.exe being 64bit is reporting problems with oracle.dataaccess.dll which is 32bit.

Oracle is not providing a "Any CPU" compilation of oracle.dataaccess.dll only "x64", "x32" target compilations of this dll are available.

Microsoft is no more providing Ole db providers for oracle.

unless we add reference a oracle.dataaccess.dll compatible with both VS 2010 and SP x64 we cannot deploy and debug in VS.

Any way out to develop,deploy,debug using VS 2010 + SP 2010 + Oracle.dataaccess.dll.

Comment: I think the process explained is to use oledb providers but I didn't know that MS's support problem. For a similar purpose, we used metaman for BDC connected to oledb providers and it was ok, that I can remember.

Answer (score 0):

We have written about this in our FAQ: http://www.lightningtools.com/bcs-meta-man/faq.aspx

Basically Visual Studio being 32bit needs the 32bit Oracle Drivers and SharePoint is 64bit and needs the 64bit drivers.

The company I work for has a tool called BCS Meta Man which will generate a .Net or Database model for you, it's a Visual Studio Extension:

[BCS Meta Man BCS Meta](http://www.lightningtools.com/bcs/bcs-meta-man.aspx)

[Man + Oracle walkthrough](http://www.lightningtools.com/blog/archive/2010/01/21/business-connectivity-services-and-oracle-with-bcs-meta-man.aspx)

You can use just the normal Visual Studio BCS Model Project to make the Model manually, but you'll probably notice very quickly that it's quite a steep learning curve:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464424(office.14).aspx